# Is Google Compute Engine VM Price included in Google Cloud $300 Free Trial

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I've set up a free trial Google Cloud account which lasts 60 days and covers $300 of costs. If I set a Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine within this Cloud, am I charged separately for the compute engine, or do $300 of the Google Cloud Free Trial cover these costs?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vendor pricing and product information. It should be addressed to the vendor via their pre-sales or support email instead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Google Compute Engine VMs are included in the free trial, but [with limitations](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/):

> **What's included in the free trial?**
>
> $300 in credit to spend on all Cloud Platform products over 60 days. During free trial, there are some product limitations. Compute Engine is limited to eight concurrent cores at a time.