# failing to deploy hadoop cluster on google cloud

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to deploy some cluster using `google cloud`. So, as the doc suggests, I run this :

```
./bdutil --bucket mybucket -n $number -P myproject --zone us-central1-a deploy
```

When I take `$number` to be 0 or 1, it deploys correctly (respectively 1 master or 1 master + 1 worker). But when I try to run the same command with `$number` set to 5, then I keep on having this kind of message :

```
*-m' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10.
*-w-0' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10.
*-w-1' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10.
*-w-2' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10....
```

where star stands for the prefix of the instance.

How can I deal with that ?

Comment: Are all of your [VM instances](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/compute/instances) starting up? Also, check your [project resource usage and quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/compute/quotas) – depending on what machine types you're using and what else you already have running in your project in the same region/zone, you may be running up against those limits so the VMs can't start. You can also apply for resource quota increases — see the link on the resource quota page.

Comment: @MishaBrukman yes all my instance are running. Btw, indeed when I want to use `click to deploy` hadoop installing, I am told that my `Quota` are limited. I believe I upgraded my account to a paid one but from `Quota` page I am directed to a google formular telling me that I can't upgrade since I am using free period offer. Weird isn't it ?

Comment: If all your instances are running but you can't SSH, try to see if you can SSH from the Developers Console via the [SSH] button.

Comment: On a related note, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27789610/3618671) about GCE limitations during a free trial. If you added billing information, it will only start getting charged after you run out of the $300 free credit trial, and then the limits will be lifted and you can apply for further resource limit increases. If you want to cancel your free trial and start paying immediately and it's not obvious how to do that from the Developers Console, please get in touch with [Google Cloud billing support](https://support.google.com/cloudbilling/).

Comment: @MishaBrukmanI can ssh in any instance created

Comment: @MishaBrukman sorry I don't want to bother you for that, but I followed the docs and I don't see any upgrade button on my console. So how can I stop free trial and begin a paid account ?

Comment: I'm guessing the upgrade button should be under the billing section of your project; please let me know if you don't find it there. See [this page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/4356091?hl=en) for how to add a new payment method.

Comment: @MishaBrukman so I added a new payment method and associated this new account to my project. Wheen I use click and deploy, I am still told that I am limited in my Quota. Is it normal ?

Comment: @MishaBrukman I have upgraded  my quotas and I am still experiencing the same issue as described in the post. Conversely, when I click to deploy it works fine. The huge issue, is that I can't use the bdutil tool since the machine name have some common prefix but random suffix, which prevent for me to deploy some `bdutil run_command` script... how can I deal with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a separate email thread with the question poster, we traced the root problem to the fact that bdutil requires setting up `gcloud compute ssh` to work with no passphrase. The [`gcloud compute` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#sshkeys) explains this setting in more depth.

In general, though this means your new GCE-specific private keyfile is unencrypted on your local machine, your SSH session itself is still secure.

As long as your local machine has both GCE SSH access as well as the "writer" permissions using `gcloud compute` commands, you'll want to keep your local machine secure anyways to prevent unexpected users from being able to overwrite your GCE metadata with new SSH keys, regardless of whether the original generated private keyfile was encrypted or not.